# Unsupported Collection interface

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I am porting a legacy application to MongoDB and therefor I'm trying to reuse the existing POJOs. I managed to succesfully persist data in MongoDB, but when I'm reading documents, it fails with the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported Collection interface: com.company.product.dto.datatypes.IObservableList
at org.springframework.core.CollectionFactory.createCollection(CollectionFactory.java:191) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readCollectionOrArray(MappingMongoConverter.java:960) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1385) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1334) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:335) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
```

Is there a way solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make sure that the type (`collectionType`) of `IObservableList` satisfies the logic the Spring code implements:

```
    if (collectionType.isInterface()) {
        if (Set.class == collectionType || Collection.class == collectionType) {
            return new LinkedHashSet<>(capacity);
        }
        else if (List.class == collectionType) {
            return new ArrayList<>(capacity);
        }
        else if (SortedSet.class == collectionType || NavigableSet.class == collectionType) {
            return new TreeSet<>();
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported Collection interface: " + collectionType.getName());
        }
    }
```

see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5.0.x/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/CollectionFactory.java

Comment: The existing POJOs are quite large. Rather then changing them, I wish I could solve this in another way. Is it possible to somehow register the constructor for ObservableList, so that it gets invoked?

Comment: Does IObservableList actually implements one of the interfaces mentioned in the CollectionFactory? Is it a List perhaps?

Comment: Yes. Here it is: `interface IObservableList<E extends IObservableObject> extends IObservableObject, Serializable, List<E>,
        Iterable<E>`

Comment: In this case I guess, you need to configure MappingMongoConverter with the List type. It looks like it uses some sort of properties file so have a look there.